# Does goji work with Google App Engine/Go?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I would like to develop application with Goji and Google App Engine/Go.

I copied and pasted sample code from
https://github.com/zenazn/goji and changed func name from "main" to "init".

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/zenazn/goji"
    "github.com/zenazn/goji/web"
)

func hello(c web.C, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %s!", c.URLParams["name"])
}

func init() {
    goji.Get("/hello/:name", hello)
    goji.Serve()
}
```

and Run this application

```
 # goapp serve
```

but this application says

```
 bad runtime process port ['']

 2014/06/01 08:35:30.125553 listen tcp :8000: bind: address already in use
```

How can I use Goji with GAE/Go? Or I cannot use Goji with GAE/Go?

Answer (score 5):

`init` functions are special, in that they're run automatically to initialize modules. By serving you app in an init function, you've stopped the initialization of your code mid-way (because `goji.Serve` never terminates). Probably what's happening is that something depends on runtime flags, and you're running before they're parsed.

What you can do is write a single app engine handler that forwards the serving the `goji.DefaultMux`. I've not tested it, but something like this should work:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/zenazn/goji"
    "net/http"
)

func init() {
    http.Handle("/", goji.DefaultMux)
    ... Register your goji handlers here
}
```

Comment: thanks! I changed "HandleFunc" -> "Handle", and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine in my dev server.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/zenazn/goji"
    "github.com/zenazn/goji/web"
)

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "index page")
}

func hello(c web.C, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %s!", c.URLParams["name"])
}

func init() {
    http.Handle("/", goji.DefaultMux)
    goji.Get("/", index)
    goji.Get("/hello/:name", hello)
}
```